# Network Link Conditioner not working

Tags: macos, network

I am a web developer and I recently found out about Network Link Conditioner, but I can't get it to work.

It appears to be working, but when I load anything in a browser, the speed is not changed, regardless of whether or not I use 100% packet loss, etc.

Can anyone tell from this log what might be causing this?

OS 10.7.5, Xcode 4.4.1.

I have tried uninstalling and rebooting in various sequences but no improvement.

Also did the steps here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414676/network-link-conditioner-seems-to-have-no-effect-on-network-behavior-on-lion-mo

When I switch it on or off, I get this in the Console:

```
1/19/13 3:28:19.142 PM [0x0-0x38038].com.apple.systempreferences: System Preferences(683,0x10e0b1000) malloc: *** auto malloc[683]: error: GC operation on unregistered thread. Thread registered implicitly. Break on auto_zone_thread_registration_error() to debug.
1/19/13 3:28:19.533 PM NLCd: API Version mismatch
1/19/13 3:28:19.534 PM com.apple.nlcd: Jan 19 15:28:19 Jason.local NLCd[698] <Notice>: API Version mismatch
1/19/13 3:28:19.534 PM [0x0-0x38038].com.apple.systempreferences: _nlc_stop_simulation: (os/kern) failure
1/19/13 3:28:19.534 PM System Preferences: process command (simulate) failed
1/19/13 3:28:19.536 PM System Preferences: Stopping Network Link Conditioner
1/19/13 3:28:19.537 PM NLCBackgroundApp: Received callback that simulator was stopped!
1/19/13 3:28:31.408 PM [0x0-0x38038].com.apple.systempreferences: _nlc_start_simulation: (os/kern) failure
1/19/13 3:28:31.409 PM System Preferences: process command (simulate) failed
1/19/13 3:28:31.441 PM System Preferences: Starting Network Link Conditioner
1/19/13 3:28:37.105 PM _securityagent: audit warning: allsoft
1/19/13 3:28:37.105 PM _securityagent: audit warning: soft /var/audit
1/19/13 3:28:37.106 PM _securityagent: audit warning: closefile /var/audit/20130119222807.20130119222837
1/19/13 3:29:07.100 PM _securityagent: audit warning: allsoft
1/19/13 3:29:07.100 PM _securityagent: audit warning: soft /var/audit
1/19/13 3:29:07.100 PM _securityagent: audit warning: closefile /var/audit/20130119222837.20130119222907
1/19/13 3:29:37.104 PM _securityagent: audit warning: allsoft
1/19/13 3:29:37.104 PM _securityagent: audit warning: soft /var/audit
1/19/13 3:29:37.105 PM _securityagent: audit warning: closefile /var/audit/20130119222907.20130119222937
1/19/13 3:30:07.103 PM _securityagent: audit warning: allsoft
1/19/13 3:30:07.103 PM _securityagent: audit warning: soft /var/audit
1/19/13 3:30:07.103 PM _securityagent: audit warning: closefile /var/audit/20130119222937.20130119223007
```

Comment: Why is this getting voted down? This is a legit issue I am having.

Comment: I get similar errors: OSX 1.7.5 *** 
4/12/13 4:19:08.249 PM [0x0-0x1e01e].com.apple.systempreferences: _nlc_start_simulation: (os/kern) failure
***
4/12/13 4:19:08.351 PM [0x0-0x1e01e].com.apple.systempreferences: System Preferences(308,0x1114c5000) malloc: *** auto malloc[308]: error: GC operation on unregistered thread. Thread registered implicitly. Break on auto_zone_thread_registration_error() to debug.

Comment: for those looking for an alternative, I found that Speed Limit works for me: http://mschrag.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

Network Link Conditioner must be run from an administrator account to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

These warning messages are generated by auditd...

The above indicates that the soft (disk space) limit for all filesystems has been exceeded.  Your system is running low on disk space.

> audit warning: soft /var/audit

The above indicates that the soft limit for this directory has been exceeded.

> audit warning: closefile /var/audit/20091208225521.20091210084714

The above indicates that a trail file has been closed, so can now be post-processed.  After the audit log gets larger than a certain size (see /etc/security/audit_control) auditd will close the trail file and open a new one.

For more information see auditd(8), audit_warn(5), and audit_control(5).   You may want also see the documentation on trustedbsd.org:  http://www.trustedbsd.org/docs.html

Source:

http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/8tBh4AyzX5tdrZYC5PaH

---

See also:

[Common Criteria Configuration and Administration Guide](http://www.apple.com/support/security/commoncriteria/CC_AdminGuide.pdf)

Oracle: [How to Change Audit Flags](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-4078/6jd6cjs6q/index.html)